# How to get the largest initial values of multiplied columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

I'm tracking performance for some athletes and we need a way to see their "Best" workout numbers meaning the highest numbers of (rep × weight).

The table looks like this:

[image: Before]

The reps and the weight are different columns and the Dates are 2x merged.

In the above table, the result should read:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- paste in **C2** and drag down:

  ```
  =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(E2:J2, 
   "select E*F,E,F,G*H,G,H,I*J,I,J 
    label E*F'',G*H'',I*J''")), , 999^99), 
   MAX({E2*F2, G2*H2, I2*J2})&" (.*)"), " "), 1, 2)
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- fix for empty cells:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
  IF(E2:J2="", 0, E2:J2), 
  "select Col1*Col2,Col1,Col2,Col3*Col4,Col3,Col4,Col5*Col6,Col5,Col6 
  label Col1*Col2'',Col3*Col4'',Col5*Col6''")), , 999^99), 
  MAX({E2*F2, G2*H2, I2*J2})&" (.*)"), " "), 1, 2))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm going to study this so I can learn why!  lol

Comment: I get an error for blank spaces.  Is there an easy way for the QUERY function to see blank spaces as zeros?

Comment: @Ashkaan sure it is. answer updated.

Comment: You're a wizard.  Thank you so very much.  You nailed it.